# Is there a canonical duplicate for "how does the C-like conditional operator work?"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

People as questions about the C-style conditional/ternary operator (`a?b:c`) on a semi-regular basis. Do we have a canonical duplicate for this type of question?

If not, can we create one, and what should it be tagged? Since it applies to a large variety of languages (C, C++, C#, Objective-C, Java, JavaScript... the list goes on), we can't exactly tag it with a specific language, but at the same time, it's not language-agnostic. Even so, since its semantics are the same in all languages, it seems like having a canonical answer would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, the semantics aren't *quite* the same in C and C++: In C, the result is always an rvalue, not so in C++. It's quite conceivable there are slight differences from either to other languages.

Comment: @Deduplicator Okay, that's technically true, though it wouldn't make a canonical answer any less useful for the plethora of other languages.

Comment: Yes and people make the same mistake in assuming that the equality operator (==) has equivalent semantics across languages. A canonical question/answer would not be useful. How would such an answer be phrased? "It's the same, except technically not really..." and you can see where it goes from there.

Comment: @remyabel The differences in the equality operator are *considerably* more dramatic than the differences in the ternary operator.